# Ionic V3 App not Displaying Content in Ionic View

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-view

I've been testing my application in FireFox, but now that I am trying to demo it on my device via the Ionic View app none of my content is displaying. The only thing that appears when loading the app from Ionic View is the Header which contains an image and a side-menu button. The side-menu displays but there is none of my content in it, just a white ion-menu container.

**<UPDATE>**
I've pretty much determined that no typescript gets processed when using the Ionic View app, and the only content displayed is the pure HTML from the app.html file (hence why the ion-menu is there but not the items inside of it, since it populates with data from a JSON file). Currently looking for a solution as to why. Anyone know if the parameters in the app.component.ts constructor could have any impact on this? Mine are:

```
constructor(public platform: Platform, private http: Http, private translate: TranslateService, private config: Config) {
```

**</UPDATE>**

ionic info returns:

```
local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.7
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova : 1.4.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
Cordova Platforms : none
Ionic Framework : ionic-angular 3.4.0

System:
Node : v8.1.0
OS : OS X El Capitan
Xcode : Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014
ios-deploy : 1.9.1
ios-sim : 6.0.0
npm : 5.0.3
```

Package.json contents:

```
{
"name": "blue-hill-mobile",
"version": "0.0.1",
"author": "Ionic Framework",
"homepage": "http://bluehilldata.com",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
"build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
"lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
"ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
"ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
},
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "4.1.3",
"@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
"@angular/core": "4.1.3",
"@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
"@angular/http": "4.1.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
"@ionic-native/core": "3.10.2",
"@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
"ionic-angular": "3.4.0",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"rxjs": "5.4.0",
"sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
"zone.js": "0.8.12"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.7",
"@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.4.0",
"@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.3.1",
"typescript": "2.3.3"
},
"description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

I have no cordova plugins installed and looked everywhere online, however every instance of this problem seemed to be in versions 1 or 2, and specifically dealt with using the ionic run/emulate command. Has anyone seen this problem before or know where I can find a resource to resolve it?? Let me know if you'd like me to post some code, but I'm not sure which part of my code would be relevant.

Comment: You can add some `alert(...)` messages to see which lines of code are being reached, and which is the last message shown, so we can take a look at that part of the code...

Comment: Thank you this helped me figure out that typescript doesn't seem to be getting reached at all in Ionic View, I updated the original post with what I found. Any further suggestions on how to debug this?